# LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции. ФАЙЛ: MSVCRT.lib

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Проект CMake. Как я понял, ошибка связанна с компилятором, добавление в файл CMakeList.txt строки:

```
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MD")
```

проблему не решило. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ым... Написать функцию `main`, разумеется. Почему вы ее не написали и на что вы надеялись? И при чем здесь вообще какой-то `/MD`?

Comment: так она есть. ещё одну добавлять?

Comment: чёрт, ты гений!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил название WinMain на main